# How to apply subversion patch between two branches

Tags: svn, branch, diff, patch

I am using version 1.8.10 of the subversion command line tools and version 1.8.8.25755 of TortoiseSVN on a Windows 7 platform (all 64-bit).

Code at my company is maintained in separate branches for each release.  Code for release in February will be in branch1; code for release in April will be in branch2.  Following the February release, I would like to compare the code in branch2 with that in branch1 to ensure that no changes are lost between the two and create a patch file that will modify branch2 to have the same content as branch1.

I am able to use the SVN command line tools to create a patch file using:

`svn diff --old=branch1 --new=branch2 > differences.diff`

The problem surfaces when I try to apply the patch file.  Using a very basic command to apply the patch:

`svn patch differences.diff c:\temp\branch1`

results in no changes to branch1.

The `svn patch --help` indicates that I should expect to see an output line generated to the screen that indicates whether changes are applied or rejected; I am seeing absolutely no output.  `--help` also indicates that the patch file should have a line indicating the revision of the branch to which the patch can be cleanly applied and gives the format for this line.  My patch file contains no line matching the stated format.

(I have also tried applying the patch using TortoiseSVN, but Tortoise appears to be somewhat particular in that it will only apply Tortoise-generated patches.)

My question then, is there some magic to applying a patch file that I am not seeing?  Or, is my command for generating the patch file correct?  Or, is what I'm trying to accomplish (patching WC2 to look like WC1) simply not supported?

TIA for whatever help/guidance you can provide.

Comment: Did your read content of `differences.diff` before patching? Is it valid patch?

Comment: This is my first attempt at creating .diff files, so I'm not an expert, but from what I've been able to find online, it looks like a valid patch... apart from the line noted in my OP that (according to --help) should be present to indicate to which branch the patch can be cleanly applied.

Answer (score 0):

Your format of diff  assumes PWD at the moment of diffing as immediate common parent of branch1 and branch2 dirs (in WC, obviously)

Any other PWD will produce invalid (or, more probably - empty) diff

More bullet-proof style of diff is `svn diff /URL/OF/BRANCH1 /URL/OF/BRANCH2 ...`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not sure I follow the point you're making here.  branch1 and branch2 are valid WCs of a repository and produce what looks like a valid .diff file.  Following your post, I created a .diff file using the same command from OP and the URLs of the repository branches.  The resulting .diff file has the same content as the file created from WCs; however, the entries are in a different sequence.  (The same five files show as diffs, but they are ordered 2,5,4,3,1, vs. 1,2,3,4,5 in the original .diff.)  I attempted to apply this .diff with same result - no joy.